# My website doesn't load index.php automatically, instead it loads the router login page: mysite/cgi-bin/login.cgi

Tags: php

I have a live project placed on my server at home running Ubuntu 12.04.1, but when I go to the website URL from another router(out of LAN which has the project server): www.mysite.com, then I get directed to the router page which is: mysite/cgi-bin/login.cgi with a note: "page not found". mysite.com/index.php is working fine!

I have edited sites-available for mysite.com and added DirectoryIndex as below

```
<Directory />
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/mysite>
     DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

I also tried adding "DirectoryIndex index.php" in .htaccess file which locates in the mysite folder with no luck.

Restarted Apache2 many times!

Would you please hint me on this?

Thank you!

Comment: It would appear that your router is intercepting and handling requests on Port 80.  You should probably turn off WAN (external) administration on the router and set it to forward port 80 to the web server.

Comment: Already the remote management is disabled and I am already forwarding to port 80, I tried both ways: start port=80, end port=80. Also, start port=80 and destination port=80, but with no luck :(

Comment: Did you set the internal IP as the server?  If you set the internal IP as the *router's* internal IP then I imagine you'd see this behavior as well.  You have to forward the connection to the server's IP.

Comment: @David: Yes I set the internal IP address for the server in the LAN which is: 192.168.3.60. My gateway IP is: 192.168.3.1. I also changed the server LAN IP to WAN IP but with no luck again :( Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: start port on your router will not work, as even locally your routers web interface runs on port 80. Try setting that port to 8080 as your start port and destination port 80 on your local computer. Then access the site by going to [[PUBLIC WAN IP]]:8080

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to specify a page when no other is selected like this? This is what I have on my index.php page:

```
 <?php
    $page_ID = "";
    if(isset($_GET['pageID'])) $page_ID = $_GET['pageID'];      
?>



 <div id="content">
            <?php 
                $page_ID = "";
                if(isset($_GET['pageID'])) $page_ID = $_GET['pageID'];

                if( $page_ID == "ContactMe" ) {
                        include("ContactMe.php");
                } 
                elseif( $page_ID == "Default" || $page_ID=="") {
                        include("Default.php"); //DEFAULT PAGE WHEN "page" NOT SPECIFIED      
                }
            ?>
 </div>
```

Also, on every other page, I put something like this as a header to set the $page_ID:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["pageID"]) && $_GET["pageID"]=="ContactMe"):
?>
```